# Seasonality detecting with Fourier Transform in R and Python

Tags: python, r

I am looking for seasonality in Google's Stock data. I already did it succesfully with R

```
library(quantmod)
library(TSA)
a=getYahooData("GOOGL",start=20130101,end=20160127,freq="daily")
a=log(a$Close)-lag(log(a$Close))
a=na.exclude(a)
periodogram(a)
```

[Periodogram with R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzj8L.png)

Now I want to do it with Python because I've found better support for algorithmic trading available.
Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 27)
df = web.DataReader("GOOGL", 'yahoo', start, end)
# import data from yahoo finance
z=np.array(df)
# convert data to array in order to manipulate with numpy
y=z[:,5]
# column with close prices
logR=np.diff(np.log(y))
# logarithmic returns
periodgram = signal.periodogram(logR)
plt.plot(periodgram)
plt.show()
# periodgram graph
```

[Periodogram with Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2kEn.png)

What is wrong with my code in Python? Why do my periodograms look so different?

Comment: In the R code one would normally write the RHS of the statement with the lags as  `diff(log(a$Close))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`periodogram` returns a pair, `(f, Pxx)`.  You should be using:

```
...
f, Pxx = signal.periodogram(logR)
plt.plot(f, Pxx)
...
```

It still looks quite different from the R output; maybe you wanted a different column?

Note that you can access the columns of the pandas data frame directly, using:

```
logR = np.diff(np.log(df["Adj Close"]))
```

or if you want Close instead, using:

```
logR = np.diff(np.log(df.Close))
```

Comment: I think there may be some difference between the dates or even the data mining methods. Thank you, may I ask why the need to use a pair? @Neapolitan

Comment: If you use `plot(array)` then matplotlib will produce one plot line for each row of the array, with x from 1 to n where n is the number of columns.